# Simultaneous use and sharing of public methods - right approach?

Tags: javascript, oop

As title says, lets say that I have a `class` with many `methods` and 80% of those:

- I need to establish also as a public (1:1 functionality)
- They use each other

What approach is the best in terms of extending and testing in the future? Of course below examples are trivial, but lets assume that I got class with 20-30 methods inside. If it help, the project is written in ReactJS.

**Approach 1:**

This approach is the fastest for me.

- No code repetition
- I am utilizing `functions` inside `class`, also sharing outside
- Some functions depends on other

```js
class Approach1 {
  names = [];

  /* Establish methods for users also */
  publicApi = {
    check: this.check,
    setValue: this.setValue
  };

  /**
   * Public method 1
   * @public
   * @param {string} name
   * @returns {boolean}
   */
  check = name => name === "foo";

  /**
   * Public method 2 using internally method 1
   * @public
   * @param {string} name
   * @returns {boolean}
   */
  setValue = name => {
    if (this.check(name)) names.push(name);
  };
}
```

**Approach 2:**

I don't think this approach is good.

- Code repetition
- I am utilizing `functions` inside `class`, also sharing outside
- Functions not depending on each other

```js
class Approach2 {
  names = [];

  /* Establish methods for users also */
  publicApi = {
    check: this.check,
    setValue: this.setValue
  };

  /**
   * Public method 1
   * @public
   * @param {string} name
   * @returns {boolean}
   */
  check = name => name === "foo";

  /**
   * Public method 2 with own implementation
   * @public
   * @param {string} name
   * @returns {boolean}
   */
  setValue = name => {
    if (name === "foo") names.push(name);
  };
}
```

**Approach 3:**

This approach looks better, but I see a lot of additional code.

- Additional code (I need to encapsulate almost every private method)
- I am separating same `functions` to private and public
- Private `method` can depends on each other
- Public `methods` always depends on private `methods`

```js
class Approach3 {
  names = [];

  /* Establish methods for users also */
  publicApi = {
    check: this.check,
    setValue: this.setValue
  };

  /**
   * Private method 1
   * @private
   * @param {string} name
   * @returns {boolean}
   */
  _check = name => name === "foo";

  /**
   * Private method 2
   * @private
   * @param {string} name
   */
  _setValue = name => {
    if (this._check(name)) names.push(name);
  };

  /**
   * Public method 1 (encapsulating private method)
   * @public
   * @param {string} name
   * @returns {boolean}
   */
  check = name => _check(name);

  /**
   * Public method 2 (encapsulating private methods 1 and 2)
   * @public
   * @param {string} name
   */
  setValue = name => {
    if (this._check(name)) this._setValue(name);
  };
}
```

Thank you for any tips :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Approach 1 looks totally fine. What you need to think first of all - is public contract. Whether some public function use another public inside or not - not important. As you still need to cover with tests each piece of public API.

p.s. having 20-30 public methods inside one class - is a good time to rethink the design and split class to multiple classes/modules to comply with [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle):)